# How to compress request payload while using apollo rest client

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using React with Apollo client for my FE application and the backend application is build on springboot.

In backend I have spring configurations which enables me to compress the payload into **gzip** while posting the response over the wire. Also I have setup the config in my reverse proxy to deflate requests. As a result the FE application is able to consume the compressed payload from Backend application.

I would also like to compress my request payload which I am posting to the backend. Is there a way I can enable this while using apollo-rest client. Any pointers would be of great help.